# Option similar to VS' IntelliSense's "Pre-select most recently used member" (C# exclusive option)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2013

So, in Visual Studio, there is an IntelliSense option that allows a quick pre-selection from the auto completion list based on the most recently used member.
this is the how the setting looks like in VS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7qV3.png
I looked around but couldn't find anything that will give me the same result in VS when coding with C++.

I did find an option called "Member List Commit Aggressive" (Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced).
this option did help me to achieve a different result which I got used to in C# so I enabled it, though still not the one I wanted.
when set to true, it will pre-select a member in the list as you write something (not just display it, but pre-select it as well, if it matches a member in the list of course).
I thought I might add this just to clear any possible confusion:
what I'm asking for (if exist) is an option to get pre-selection without writing anything, right after you write down the dot operator (that is if a recently used member does exist of course).

I'm not entirely sure if it's possible with C++'s IntelliSense or not,
but if it doesn't and there's another way to achieve the same result, I'd like to hear about that as well.
though I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and as far as I know extensions are not available for Express editions.

P.S
This is my first question ever in StackOverflow so please bear with me if something is not right.
I've read and tried to follow the suggestions I was given before I could post a question.
I've tagged the post and tried to explain the situation in a detailed, yet summarized way.
if I've done something wrong or if something can be improved, please tell me.

Thanks in advance!
Leo.